# Installing TeXlive on Windows is a security problem

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I have a "security agent" on my computer which impedes texlive install:

1. There are packages with file names ending with `.doc.tar.xz`.
2. The
   installer decompresses the archives, which normaly results in an
   executable file, ending with `.doc`.
3. Apparently this triggers my
   Windows "security agent" and it removes executable permissions
   from these files.
4. With the executable permissions removed, the
   installer is unable to untar the archive, resulting in an error and the end of the installation attempt.

I encounter similar problems when there is a `.win32` in the file name, but not always. For instance the package `luatex.win32` will always fail to untar, but `bibtex.win32` untar-ed without errors.

I must now find a way to manually, pre-untar all the archives and then trigger the installer. How can this be done? It appears the `-in-place` option can be used for that but I wouldn't know how to proceed.

Comment: Windows doesn't have 'executable files' by flag, only by name, and `.doc` or `.win32` do not appear on the usual list. Perhaps you mean your security package blocks access to these files? We will likely need some screenshots to help at all, but it may be off-topic for us  (a Windows issue).

Comment: Have you tried installing TeXLive as portable, into your user home directory? That might avoid triggering file permissions. Maybe, maybe not, but worth a try.

Comment: @JosephWright The security agent automagically removes executable rights on these files for each and every context, including Administrator and System. Of course this is a Windows issue, but I do not have the privileges to change anything about that. I come here hoping for a solution using only the texlive installer, or at least parts of it.

Comment: @RobtAll Yes, I have. This did not prevent the problem.

Comment: I don't see that this is at all solvable at the TeX side: if access to the files is blocked then they cannot be used. One could I suppose copy a complete installation from another machine (as suggested by user12711), but I suspect the aggressive security described will also disallow that.

Comment: @JosephWright this is exactly what I did. I installed texlive portable on another machine, copied the result to a usb stick and from there on my computer. The files are never inaccessible. They merely get all executable permissions revoked automatically when written or copied. I can (re-)grant these permissions manually, but that doesn't help with the automatic installer. I think it would work without problems if the `-J` option was used  with `untar`. The problem is that `unxz` and `untar` are two steps and the first step writes a file with a name the securtiy agent does not like.

Answer (score 3):

If your "security agent" is blocking TeXLive and you are not allowed to accommodate TeXLive (which could theoretically open doors to other untrusted programs or viruses), then TeXLive may still be run on your Windows machine using a couple of workaround approaches.  They don't, however, fix the underlying cause of why you can't install TeXLive in the firstplace.  So if you can't fix that conveniently, these will work:

**One Approach:**  From TeXLive, download the full TeXLive Distribution ISO and "burn" that to DVD or external memory card, like a thumbdrive or SD card.  ["burn" means you use special software to copy an iso, so that it's "binary" format stays intact.  A regular "copy" will not work, as it rearranges the "bits" from one file format to the destinations file format].  So, this may also involve you downloading another app designed to "burn" iso files to their target destinations, unless you already have such a tool installed.]

**Another Approach:** [much more Laborious, put potentially more convenient after it's done]  Use a Virtual Machine, with Linux running within, and TeXLive running within Linux... all on your Windows Machine.

[A virtual machine allows you to run an alternate operating system within Windows, but everything is "sandboxed" within the virtual machine, and software run within the virtual machine is isolated and kept from interfering with Windows operating system functions]

**--Download** a Virtual Machine like **VirtualBox**

**--Download** a Linux operating system like Ubuntu or **Kubuntu** (they install as iso files into the virtual machine as a later step)

**--Install** the virtual machine.  With **Virtualbox** you will be warned that it will disrupt your network connections during the install.  You can click NO if you want don't want to allow the VirtualBox a network connection, and then you can configure that later as desired, or use a manually downloaded texlive-full iso to install within the Virtual Box.  **ALSO** make sure you serve 4GB or more RAM for Kubuntu (2GB minimum).  Windows will be left with the remainder RAM reserved for itself (make sure it has at least an equal amount of RAM left).

**--** click **NEW** from Virtualbox taskbar, and **Create Virtual Machine** select the operating system you want the Virtual Machine to Run As, NAME:**whatever**; TYPE:**Linux**; VERSION:**Kubuntu**.  [at this point you will need to select your Ubuntu or Kubutu iso file from Virtualbox]

--If you setup the network connection, apply all updates to your *Virtualbox Kubuntu operating system* first, then with Kubuntu fully up-to-date, you can just open up the terminal-console window and issue this one command, which will download and install the full TeXLive distribution into VirtualBox.  This command will work on Ubuntu or Kubuntu: `sudo apt install texlive-full` from the terminal window.

BUT, I hope you find a more convenient answer than that lengthy workaround.

Comment: I cannot run virtual machines on this system either. I ended up doing a portable installation at another machine and copied the result to this computer using a pen drive.

Comment: @Bananguin So, copying the portable installation worked? Good! This is one reason why I recommend portable. For example, I can duplicate my own Windows-side up-to-date TeXLive portable, and run it on an office machine that otherwise has a too-old version of TeXLive.